# Договорённости в языке программирования

Tags: c#

Слышал, что нужно использовать в цикле `for` переменную `i`, затем если вложенный цикл и `i` занята, то `j` , потом `k`

Откуда  берутся эти договорённости и как узнать обо всех ? спасибо!

Comment: Framework design guidelines - ест такая книга от автора дотнета + есть такой раздел на msdn

Comment: @tym32167 ну i и j -эти договоренности вне какого либо языка или фреймворка. Правда, может быть в каком-нибудь 1С это по другому.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну неудивительно, что для идентичных конструкций похожие рекомендации. Но одно дело абстрактные рекомендации для всех языков и другое - конкретные для C# от создателей .NET.

Comment: А за что на человека с минусами накинулись?)

Answer (score 1):

`i`, `j`, `k` это не просто произвольные переменные цикла, это именно индексные переменные.

Такая запись допустима (псевдокод):

```
for (i = 0; i < words.size; i++) print(words[i])
```

потому, что в любом месте программы `i` наверняка будет использоваться в тандеме с именем массива, и сразу будет понятно, для чего эта переменная нужна.

Но в современных языках переменной цикла обычно является не индекс массива, а ссылка на его элемент, и использование `i` вредит читаемости кода.

```
for (i: words) print(i)
```

Правильнее было бы дать переменной более осмысленное имя

```
for (word: words) print(word)
```

или хотя бы нейтральное

```
for (elem: words) print(elem)
```

Также переменная цикла может быть не индексом и не ссылкой, а просто значением, в таком случае `i` тоже не подходит в качестве имени

```
for (x = 0; x < 10; i += 0.5) print(x, f(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Договоренности берутся из опыта каких-либо разработчиков ПО по всему миру. Существуют даже специальные комитеты для согласования стандартов по определенным областям. Эти договоренности есть практически во всех отраслях и профессиях.

Вообще, они могут появиться откуда угодно и прежде чем дойдут до вас, пройдут через "глухой телефон", т.е. до вас могут дойти искаженными. Собственно, что и случилось, судя по вашему вопросу. Если говорить конкретно о вашем высказывании про **i**, **j** и **k**, то это не договоренность, а рекомендация. Если вы назовете переменную цикла не **i**, а **myCustomIndex**, то ничего не изменится с точки зрения функциональности, но ваш код будет значительно шире. Чтобы понять рекомендацию, нужно понимать что такое область видимости переменной. Рекомендация звучит примерно так: чем меньше область видимости переменной, тем предпочтительнее использовать более короткое имя переменной. Это рекомендация связана с особенностями мышления и восприятия человека. Проще в очень маленьком контексте воспринимать короткие имена, чем длинные, т.к. мозг в состоянии понять смысл этой переменной и запомнить его в маленьком охвате.

К сожалению, обо всех договоренностях вы не сможете узнать (может быть есть сайты, целью которых стоит собирание такой информации, но я сомневаюсь, но если найдете - дайте знать), а если и узнаете, то поймете, что многие из них противоречат друг другу. В языке C# например, есть 2 варианта именования приватных переменных класса, первый вариант говорит, что нужно начинать с символа подчеркивания (`_`), а второй, что нужно начинать с символов "`m_"`. В большинстве случаев по ходу изучения конкретной области программирования вы будете натыкаться на какие-то соглашения (они ещё называются Style-Guide), которых придерживается группа людей, которые используют данный язык/фреймворк/технологию или что-то ещё. Это не значит, что вам тоже нужно это делать, но вообще это желательно. Единообразие облегчает понимание.